# Performance evaluating excel cells with python

Tags: python, excel

I am trying to compare 2 columns of an excel file with a 2D-matrix row by row with python. My excel file contains 20'100 rows and the computing time via Pycharm is more than 1 hour. Is there any way how to do these value comparisons more time efficient?

```
import openpyxl as xl
from IDM import idm_matrix

# load and create excel file
wb = xl.load_workbook('Auswertung_C33.xlsx')
result_wb = xl.Workbook() #new workbook for results
result_sheet = result_wb.create_sheet('Ergebnisse') #create new sheet in result file
result_wb.remove(result_wb['Sheet'])
sheet = wb['TriCad_Format']

# copy 1st row
first_row = sheet[1:1]
list_first_row =[]
for item in first_row:
    list_first_row.append(item.value)
result_sheet.append(list_first_row)

# Value check
for row in range(2, sheet.max_row + 1):
    row_list = []
    for col in range(1, sheet.max_column + 1):
        cell = sheet.cell(row, col)
        row_list.append(cell.value)
    for matrix in idm_matrix:
        if row_list[7] is None:
            continue
        elif matrix[0] in row_list[7]:
            if row_list[14] is None or matrix[1] != row_list[14]:
                result_sheet.append(row_list)


print("saving file...")
result_wb.save('Auswertung.xlsx') #saves the file in a new wb
print("Done!")
```

Thanks for your help!
Alex

----- Sample of Data ------

```
Input:

BEZ                 | _IDM
Schirmsprinkler-SU5 | EAL
```

--> if column BEZ contains the string 'Schirmsprinkler' and column _IDM has any value, the row should be copied. If the column _IDM is empty, the row is fine and should not be copied. There are many strings in BEZ where _IDM should be empty, so thats why I am trying to put them all in the df_idm lists. However, it doesn't work with an empty string "".

Update 20th of May 2020:

```
import openpyxl as xl
from IDM import idm_matrix
import pandas as pd

# EXCEL DATA FRAME
xl_file = 'Auswertung_C33.xlsx'
df_excel = pd.read_excel(xl_file, sheet_name="TriCad_Format")

# IDM LIST DATA FRAME
df_idm = pd.DataFrame(idm_matrix, columns=['LongName', 'ShortName'])

# REMOVE ROWS WHICH HAVE NO VALUE IN COLUMN 6
df_excel.dropna(subset=['BEZ'], inplace=True)

# MATCH ON CORRESPONDING COLUMNS
search_list = df_idm['LongName'].unique().tolist()
matches1 = df_excel[(df_excel["BEZ"].str.contains("|".join(search_list), regex=True)) &
                   (~df_excel["_IDM"].isin(df_idm["ShortName"].tolist()))]
matches2 = df_excel[(~df_excel["BEZ"].str.contains("|".join(search_list), regex=True)) & (~pd.isnull(df_excel["_IDM"]))]

# CREATE LIST OF MATCHING DATAFRAMES
sum_of_idm = [matches1, matches2]

# CREATE NEW WORKBOOK
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Ergebnisse.xlsx')
pd.concat(sum_of_idm).to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Ergebnisse", index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Why not use a data analytics library like `pandas` or `numpy` to import data and compare without loops?

Comment: I cannot find `IDM` module in [PyPI](https://pypi.org/). Though there is `idm`. Please show `type(idm_matrix)`. What is this object? Usually you import methods with `import` lines, not direct objects.

Comment: I have no experience with pandas or numpy. IDM is a python file where I have a 2x100 matrix named idm_matrix.

Comment: How can I compare values of the matrix with a column in excel via pandas/numpy? Can you help me with my example?

Comment: People's interpretation of `matrix` may just be a nested list of lists. The only module I know in Python that supports arrays (where matrix is 2D array) is `numpy`. This module (of which I cannot find) may extend `numpy`. Can you please post the output of `type(idm_matrix)`?

Comment: It is just a file where I put an array, nothing else. See the link here [link](https://imgur.com/a/SAIDKRW)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are handling data requiring comparison checks, consider Pandas, the third-party data analytics library of Python for several reasons:

- Import and export Excel features that can interface with `openpyxl`
- Ability to interact with many Python data objects (`list`, `dict`, `tuple`, `array`, etc.)
- Vectorized, comparison logic that is more efficient than nested `for` loops
- Use whole, named objects (`DataFrame` and `Series`) for bulk, single call, set-based operations
- Avoid working with unnamed, numbered rows and cells that impacts readability

Specifically, you can migrate your `idm_matrix` to a data frame and import Excel data to a data frame for column comparison or by a single call [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) (for exact match) or [`Series.str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) (for partial match) followed by logic filter.

**Note**: Without reproducible example the below code uses information from posted code but needs to be tested on actual data. Adjust any `Column#` from original Excel worksheet as needed:

```
import openpyxl as xl
from IDM import idm_matrix
import pandas as pd

# EXCEL DATA FRAME
xl_file = 'Auswertung_C33.xlsx'
df_excel = pd.read_excel(xl_file, sheet_name="TriCad_Format")

# IDM LIST DATA FRAME
df_idm = pd.DataFrame(idm_matrix, columns = ['LongName', 'ShortName'])

# EXACT MATCH
# matches = df_excel.merge(df_idm, left_on=['Column6'], right_on=['LongName'])    

# PARTIAL MATCH
search_list = df_idm['LongName'].unique().tolist()
matches = df_excel[(~df_excel["Column6"].str.contains("|".join(search_list), regex=True)) &
                   (pd.isnull(df_excel["_IDM"])) &
                   (df_excel["Column6"].isin(df_idm["ShortName"].tolist())]

# ADJUST EXISTING WORKBOOK
with pd.ExcelWriter(xl_file, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    writer.book = xl.load_workbook(xl_file)     
    try:
        # REMOVE SHEET IF EXISTS
        writer.book.remove(writer.book['Ergebnisse'])
        writer.save()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:    
        # ADD NEW SHEET OF RESULTS      
        matches.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Ergebnisse", index=False)
        writer.save()
```

Comment: Regex as specified here does not work with empty string. Consider not adding `""` to *ShortName* and instead use an `&` condition. Something like `df_excel["_IDM"] != ""`

Comment: Hmm ok, the problem is that I want to check specific values from LongName to be empty in Shortname. A general condition with empty _IDM cells are therefore not working. Do you have any idea how I can solve this issue?

Comment: In the body of your post please edit with a sample of data (not as [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)) and clearly show your original data and desired result. Keep only relevant columns and redact as needed.

Comment: I tried to explain it in a simple way in my post above.. Hope its clear now. I had the idea to put all these special "LongNames" in a new list and check in a separate condition if column _IDM is empty. If you have a better approach let me know. Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: One row of sample data is not enough. Please show desired result with a good batch of records. Are you changing your original needs to check *ShortName*? But from your text, you could check if NOT null AND NOT empty string: `<existing condtions> & (pd.notnull(df_excel["_IDM"]) & (df_excel["_IDM"] != "")`. But technically, last two here is redundant since they would not pass first condition. Maybe I jumped the gun in pushing you to `pandas`! It is a different Python paradigm than working with lists.

Comment: I figured it out and created a different dataframe with 2 condition where I check whether LongName is NOT in column BEZ and column _IDM is NOT null. After I combined both dataframes (matches1 and matches2) with pd.concat to on worksheet. I posted the entire code in my first post. If you have another idea, let me know. But it works pretty fine so far!

Comment: Glad you found your solution. I had feeling you just had to keep figuring it out on your own with your available data. You can combine the two matches' conditions with an OR repeating first condition and avoid `concat` at the end: `(condition1 & condition2) | (condition1 & condition3)`. Also instead of `~pd.isnull` use `pd.notnull`.

Comment: Do you have any idea how I can check, if there is any cell with the same value of the last 5 characters/numbers in a specific column of my excel file (input) and copy the entire row to my sheet?

Comment: Look into [Series.str](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.html): `df['Column'].str[-5:]`. Give it a try and ask a new question if you run into issues.